# CSS hover not working properly in my menu bar

Tags: css, mousehover

I am trying to change the `background-color` of a menu, while `mouse-hover`. But it is not working.

I have used the following CSS code:

```
#access a:hover{
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F99733, #E47300) repeat scroll 0 0     transparent; 
 }
```

Please take a look at the page [CLICK HERE](http://beta.cpmfinancial.co.uk/)

Comment: what browser do you use ? Firefox , chrome , IE ?

Comment: background color is changing are happening and your `a:hover` is over ride by `a:focus` look into that

Comment: I would like to work it in all major browsers

Comment: Thanks Thirumalai murugan, but how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I like using a grey `inset` `box-shadow` to style my element and then I can simply swap the background colours on hover.

### HTML

```
<div>
    Example
</div>
```

### CSS

```
div
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    background-color: #0ff;
            box-shadow: inset 0px -50px 75px -50px #000;
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px -50px 75px -50px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px -50px 75px -50px #000;
}

div:hover
{
    background-color: #bff;
}
```

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/5Q5h9/

Answer (score 0):

```
#access a:hover{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #F99733, #E47300) repeat scroll 0 0     transparent; 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , #F99733, #E47300) repeat scroll 0 0     transparent; 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(center top , #F99733, #E47300) repeat scroll 0 0     transparent; 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(center top , #F99733, #E47300) repeat scroll 0 0     transparent; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this ,

```
background:  linear-gradient(....          
background: -moz-linear-gradient(....      ///  FF3.6+ 
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(....   ///  Chrome10+,Safari5.1+
background: -o-linear-gradient(....        ///  Opera 11.10+
background: -ms-linear-gradient(....       ///  IE10+
```

you can generate linear-gradient [HERE](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) !

Answer (score 0):

Try using this site and generate for all browsers gradient [Generate CSS3 Gradient](http://gradients.glrzad.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers use different gradient rules, try using the code below:

```
div:hover {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#F99733), to(#E47300)); /* safari & chrome */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#F99733, #E47300); /* Firefox */
    -ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFF99733,endColorstr=#FFE47300); /* IE8 */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFF99733,endColorstr=#FFE47300); /* IE 7 */
    zoom: 1;
    background: linear-gradient(#F99733, #E47300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because its having issues with your `:focus` pseudo selector which is  applied to your `<a>`.

First you need to understand that you are only supporting gecko based browsers (Mozilla Firefox) by adding the vendor prefix of -moz to your CSS.

There's a [website that helps you make gradients](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) so you can copy and paste them and they have an image as a fallback so it looks good in older browsers too.

So it will end up looking like this:

```
#access li a:hover,
#access li a:focus {
  background: #f99733;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #f99733 0%, #e47300 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#f99733), color-stop(100%,#e47300));
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #f99733 0%,#e47300 100%);
  background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #f99733 0%,#e47300 100%);
  background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #f99733 0%,#e47300 100%);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #f99733 0%,#e47300 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f99733', endColorstr='#e47300',GradientType=1 );
}
```

I find that this works for me in most cases and its based on what I understand your specific needs are.